# Is there something like `last` for `map`?

Tags: perl

In Perl, is it possible to arbitrarily end a [`map`](http://p3rl.org/map) execution, e.g. something equivalent to [`last`](http://p3rl.org/last) in a loop?

It would be a bit like this:

```
map {
    if (test == true) { last; } dosomething
} @myarray
```

Comment: See [Is "map" a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019925/is-map-a-loop) for a related question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nope. You can't `last`, `next`, etc. out of a `map`, `grep` or `sort` blocks because [they are not loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019925/is-map-a-loop).

Having said that, the code snippet in the question is poor practice because `map` should never be called in void context. They are supposed to be used to transform one list into another.

Here's a better way to write it if you really must inline it (modified after ysth's comment):

```
 $_ == 10 && last, print for 1..15;  # prints '123456789'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
About the "poor parctice" thing, well ... the "dosomething"  piece of code is intended to .... do something

Comment: @benzebuth : I wasn't talking about the `do_something`. You should be really be using `map` to return a list.

Comment: Just as you shouldn't use map in void context, you shouldn't use ?: unless you actually want the value from either branch.   `$_ == 10 && last, print for 1..15`

Comment: @ysth : Thanks for the heads up, I always forget about the comma operator.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to forget to use the comma operator this way.

Answer (score 3):

No. Use an ordinal `foreach` loop and the `last` statement.

Since 5.8.1, [map is context aware](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What%27s-wrong-with-using-grep-in-a-void-context?) - in void context, no lists are constructed.
Anyway, map is generally used to get a list from another list, evaluating expr for each element of the original list.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a do-block with a for statement modifier:

```
do {
   last if test;
   dosomething;
} for (@myarray);
```

Though using a foreach block would probably be clearer, and future maintainers of your code will thank you.

```
foreach (@myarray) {
   last if test;
   dosomething;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a long jump (`eval`/`die` pair) to bail out of any nested construct that doesn't directly support it:

```
eval { map{ die if test; dosomething } @myarray };
```

But as Zaid said, using a `for`/`foreach` loop in this case is better because you are not using the return value of `map`.

Comment: map doesn't construct a list in void context: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What%27s-wrong-with-using-grep-in-a-void-context?

Comment: @eugene => that's true, but it is a bit misleading to use `map` without the return value.  if you want the inverted position of action and values, its better to use `dosomething for ...'

Comment: the exception being when you for some reason want to provide dosomething list context (but don't actually want the returned list) - a rare case.  for provides void context to dosomething (and grep would provide scalar context)

Answer (score 2):

You want a for loop:

```
foreach ( @myarray ) { 
    last if test;
    ...
}
```

It does the same thing. `map` is for transforming one list into other lists.

Answer (score 1):

There are map-like constructs that do exactly what you want to do. Take a look at [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) and [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) (conveniently also packaged together as [List::AllUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::AllUtils)):

```
use List::MoreUtils 'first';

# get first element with a {foo} key
my $match = map { $_->{foo} eq 'some string' } @elements;
```

If you don't want to extract an element(s) from the list, then use foreach, as per the previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try goto LABEL. However I do not know how safe is that.

Comment: Someone flagged this as not being an answer, but this looks fine to me. It's probably not the best answer, given that it has no up votes and other answers have tons, but that doesn't warrant calling it not an answer.

Comment: It is a very low quality answer on a **4 year old post** that has many other better answers... it adds nothing to this question and should IMHO be downvoted and eventually deleted.

Comment: It may be "low quality", but it is not VLQ.  Just downvote and leave it.