# How can I find everything BUT certain phrases with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Ok, so I have a phrase "foo bar" and I want to find everything BUT "foo bar".
Here's my text.

> ipsum dolor foo bar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor foo bar incididunt ut labore et
>   dolore foo bar

There's a way to do this just within regex right?  I don't have to go and use strings etc. do I?

RESULT:

NOTE I can't do a nice highlighting but the bold gives you an idea (although the spaces that are before and after would also be selected but it breaks the bolding).

**ipsum dolor** *foo bar* **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,**
**consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do**
**eiusmod tempor** *foo bar* **incididunt ut labore et**
**dolore** *foo bar*

*Assume PCRE nomenclature.*

---

UPDATE 7/29/2013: it may be better to use a search and replace function in your language of choice to just 'remove' the phrases that you don't want so that you are then left with the info you do want.

Comment: Tell us what operating system.  Tell us what programming language.  Tell us the EXACT STRING you are starting with.  Tell us the EXACT STRING you expect as an answer.  Tell us what you are not allowed to use AND WHY.

Comment: See question for 'exact string'; see question for expected result. I'm not allowed to use walruses, the colour blue, or cheeky phrases concerning Vogon poetry.  I am allowed to use regex (with PCRE rules)....Why....who knows...but my guess has something to do with the walrus...or possible his hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
^(?!.*foo bar).*$
```

this should select every line that does not contain "foo bar". (?! = negative lookahead)

Comment: It's not pulling using UltaEdit.  I'm not able to test it with RegexBuddy at the time but I might be able to try it tonight.

Comment: it's not pulling with REB either. any ideas why?

Comment: the regular expression option multiline must be enabled for this to work. the tool i test with is: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: I'm confused - this won't actually produce the response specified in the question.

Answer (score 9):

In general, if `foobar` matches itself, then `(?s:(?!foobar).)*` matches anything that is *not* `foobar`, including nothing at all.

You could use that to find lines that don’t have `foobar` in them, for example, using

`^(?:(?!foobar).)*$`

You could also use your language’s `split()` function to split *on* `foobar`, which will give you all the pieces that do *not* include the split pattern.

Regarding the nasty little-known backtracking control verbs like `(*FAIL)` and `(*COMMIT)`, I haven’t yet had much occasion to use them in ‘non-toy’ programs. I find that independent subexpressions via `(?>...)` and the possessive quantifiers `*+`, `++`, `?+` etc. give me more than enough rope, so to speak.

That said, I do have one toy example of using `(*FAIL)` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092348/in-perl-how-can-i-generate-an-array-with-random-values-without-using-a-loop/4092746#4092746); it’s the very first regex solution. The reason for its being there was I wanted to force the regex engine to backtrack through all possible permutations; the real goal was merely to count how many ways it tried things.

Please understand that my two regexes there, along with  the many, many incredibly creative answers from others, are all meant to be fun, tongue-in-cheek things.  Still, one *can* learn a lot from them — once one recovers from shock. ☺

Comment: @tchrist wait...isn't this searching for "foobar" and not "foo bar"?  which may be why it's not matching in UltraEdit correctly.

Comment: @Kang: I don't know why he dropped the space, but you can put it back in; it will still work.  I don't think he meant to imply that `foobar` would match `foo bar`. :P  (Then again, in Perl 6 it *would* match, wouldn't it?)

Comment: @Alan Moore and others: This does NOT work.  It does not work as is or with the extra space inside the 'foobar' phrase.

Comment: @tchrist please see Alan and my response above.

Comment: @Keng: Then I have no idea what you actually want. Please supply the input string and the desired output. I cannot tell whether you’re talking about wanting the entire match to fail, or if you want something not to be included in a successful match.  Can't guess, so tell me.

Comment: @Keng: Barely.  How does `@pieces = split /UNWANTED/, $FULL_TEXT` **not** solve your problem?  I mentioned it early on.

Comment: @tchrist oh...yeah, that would work but because I'm severely restricted in my environment, I can't use that method. 8.0(

Comment: @Keng: Then no one can help you because you have failed to adequately explain what constraints you must work under.

Comment: @tchrist Well, I'm still looking for a regex pattern to do this regardless of whether I can or can't use C# C++ or PHP.  Regex can find everything but a word; I'm looking for everything but a phrase.  A phrase is after all just a word with an odd character somewhere in the middle that makes it look like two words to humans.

Comment: @tchrist why in the world do you think that I'm using a 'language'? Why do you think I'm even in a programming language?  There no 'split' in programming text editors.

Comment: @Keng of course there is.  `:.,.+3!perl -ne 'print join " ", reverse split /foobar/'`

Comment: @tchrist and what language is `:.,.+3!perl -ne 'print join " ", reverse split /foobar/'` from?

Comment: @Keng: It's not.  Remember, you said we weren't allowed to use language. It is, of course, an editor command.

Answer (score 2):

"remove everything except foo bar" is equivalent to "find only foo bar", which PCRE allows quite easily. Conversely, "find everything except foo bar" is equivalent to "find and remove only foo bar". So, complementation is easily done from your tools.

Aside from that, PCRE has a nasty little feature known as `*FAIL` which immediately causes a backtrack when it's encountered. So, I suppose inserting something like `(*COMMIT)foo bar(*FAIL)` into your regular expression could help. It's neither friendly nor very safe, though.

Comment: sorry, my ham-handed example lead both you and me down the wrong path.  I edited it to make it clearer....I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you want to **remove** everything except `foo bar` using UltraEdit's  "Advanced" (Perl-regex style) search feature.  The easiest way to do that is to match everything, but only *capture* `foo bar`, like this:

```
(?:(?!foo bar).)+(foo bar|$)
```

...and replace it with `$1` or `\1` (whichever style UltraEdit accepts).

I don't use UltraEdit, but in EditPadPro it converts this:

```
ipsum dolor foo bar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor foo bar incididunt ut labore et
dolore foo bar
```

...to this:

```
foo bar

foo bar
foo bar
```

...which is the result you showed in your original message.

Comment: I want to find everything BUT "foo bar".

Answer (score 1):

Here: `perl -pe 's{.*?(foo bar)?}{$1}g' <text`

> I want to find everything BUT "foo bar"

A match-only pattern without using substitution by $1 (that is usable with the empty replacement as in s{pattern}{})... not sure that is possible. You would have to gobble up chars up until `foo bar`, e.g. with `.*?(?=foo bar)`. But then the matching algorithm continues on and sees "oo bar", and would match again as there is no f.

Continuing the quest, here is a piece of perl code that gobbles up the requested parts, only with the drawback that empty captures may be returned if `foo bar` happens to be at the start of the line:

```
foreach (<>) {
        chomp;
        @_ = m{(.*?)(?:foo bar|$)}gs;
        print "[[ $_ ]]\n" for @_;
}
```

There is no substituion involved and running this on the Lorem ipsum test file will show everything but the `foo bar` parts. It is PCRE compatible, but there is no guarantees that $EDITOR will does what you envision.

Answer (score 1):

to show everything except "foo bar" and "fad bad" this worked for me:

`^(?!.*foo bar)(?!.*fad bad).*$`