# I am new to RegEx and I need to create a few RegEx scripts for a Drivers License field

Tags: regex

I need to create RegEx for two different states and I am having some trouble. Here are the requirements; one is for Washington DC and and the other for Delaware:

> **1) DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA (DC)**
>   - ***Format***: 9 Numeric (SSN) or 7 Numeric
>
> **2) DELAWARE (DE)**
>   - ***Format***: 1-7 Numeric

The RegEx I have for DC is `^(\d{7}|(\d{9})$` which doesnt seem to work.

I think I have the one for Delaware  `^(\d{1,7})$`

Comment: Geez!!  All these regex people jumping in this morning.  You guys should swing by this question and see if you can help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109147/how-can-i-find-everything-but-certain-phrases-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: ^(\d{7})|(\d{9}))$' appears to still have issue it is allowing me to enter 8 digits and also more than 9. I need it to only except either 7 digits or 9 digit but nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're still having problems try this.  I moved the parenthesis around to enclose both conditions at once.

```
^(\d{7}|\d{9})$
```

Answer (score 2):

Another posiibility which should work aswell is:

```
^\d{7}(\d{2})?$
```

Answer (score 1):

For the DC expression, you have some syntax errors. Try:

```
^(\d{7})|(\d{9})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your DC regex, you've got a parenthesis after the 7, where there should be a closing curly bracket.