# How to compare two arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays. I want to find what elements are in the second but not the first, and what elements are in the first but not the second.

Is there any way with out writing multiple loops?

Each array is something like this $array_2d_1

```
0  ARRAY(0x9929210)
   0  ARRAY(0x98df3d8)
      0  71
      1  22
      2  15
      3  10
      4  51
   1  ARRAY(0x9934900)
      0  91
      1  82
      2  28
      3  11
      4  91
```

Comment: I'm trying to use multiple for loops. But want to know if there is a better way

Comment: It depends what you mean by "compare", and it depends what you mean by "loops". :-)

Comment: I want to find the diff. What is missing and extra in array 2

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what want to change.

Comment: So basically you are using arrays to implement *bags* (sets with multiple occurrences of equal items). If no duplicate items are possible, a conversion to hashes would be simple, and with duplicates it would not be quite as simple. Basically you would iterate ofer the keys (items) of one hash, using `exists` to test the items in the other hash.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the module [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.38/lib/List/Compare.pm) for this task:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

my @arr1 = qw/5 8 12 42 99 10/;
my @arr2 = qw/10 20 12 18 99 10/;

my $lc = List::Compare->new( \@arr1, \@arr2 );

my @arr1Only = $lc->get_Lonly;
print "\@arr1 only: @arr1Only\n";

my @arr2Only = $lc->get_Ronly;
print "\@arr2 only: @arr2Only\n";
```

Output:

```
@arr1 only: 42 5 8
@arr2 only: 18 20
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid looping. This solution has four loops, but they're not nested.

```
my %a1 = map { $_ => 1 } @a1;
my %a2 = map { $_ => 1 } @a2;

my @missing_from_a1 = grep !$a1{$_}, @a2;
my @missing_from_a2 = grep !$a2{$_}, @a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like set implementation in perl right. In standard perl there is no set implementation and here is the module in cpan that can achieve what you are trying to solve [set](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Set-Scalar-1.27/lib/Set/Scalar.pm). So, we have to find out a way that we can create unique element out of the array, and hash keys in perl is unique. By using hash implementation we can  achieved the set implementation. More details you can look up here :

[Set Implementation](http://world.std.com/~swmcd/steven/perl/pm/set.html)

Answer (score 0):

To take the set difference between two sets, there must be loops involved somewhere. I am assuming you want to avoid writing out the loops every time you need to compute the set difference instead of having an [unhealthy aversion to loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092348/).

One simple way would be to abstract away the operation into a subroutine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

main();

sub main {
    my @x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    my @y = (3, 5, 7, 8, 9);

    for my $sets ( ([\(@x, @y)], [\(@y, @x)]) ) {
        print "@{ set_diff( @$sets ) }\n";
    }
}

sub set_diff {
    my $x = shift;
    my %y = map { $_ => undef } @{ $_[0] };
    return [ grep not( exists $y{$_} ), @$x ];
}
```

There are also a number of [set implementations on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=set).